# New line character in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, string

I am trying to print a message on a web page in vb.net. I am trying to get the messages in new lines. I tried using the "\r\n" and the new line character. But this is getting printed in the page instead of it comming to the next line. Please let me know if there is any alternative.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use HTML on a web page to get line breaks. For example "<br/>" will give you a line break.

Answer (score 62):

Check out `Environment.NewLine`. As for web pages, break lines with `<br>` or `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: Kudos on offering the <p> </p> solution -- it is the best one here, IMHO.

Answer (score 39):

[`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) is the most ".NET" way of getting the character, it will also emit a carriage return and line feed on Windows and just a carriage return in Unix if this is a concern for you.

However, you can also use the VB6 style [`vbCrLf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf.aspx) or [`vbCr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcr.aspx), giving a carriage return and line feed or just a carriage return respectively.

Comment: I suspect because while your answer addresses how to get the newline character that isn't actually the answer the questioner needs. What he actually needs is an HTML break. As has been covered by other answers.
None of the answers that just talk about NewLine are really answering the question.

Comment: Although, that said, the question is incredibly unclear. I guess "print a message on a web page" _could_ actually mean he is trying to use alert() or msgbox() on the web page, which would make it a whole different question.

Comment: Yeah, the question is poor if that is what he wants as he mentions "\r\n" which is C style for vbCrLf, I assumed that was the answer he was looking for.

Comment: !! - You made my day today.. I was using a StringBuilder to build and export it as csv., and NONE of the other things worked ( .Net 1.1 , so AppendLine() isn't available ). vbCrLf worked perfectly!!!

Comment: From the title of the topic, this is what I expected, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The proper way to do this in VB is to use on of the VB constants for newlines.  The main three are

- vbCrLf = "\r\n"
- vbCr = "\r"
- vbLf = "\n"

VB by default doesn't allow for any character escape codes in strings which is different than languages like C# and C++ which do.  One of the reasons for doing this is ease of use when dealing with file paths.

- C++ file path string: "c:\\foo\\bar.txt"
- VB file path string: "c:\foo\bar.txt"
- C# file path string: C++ way or @"c:\foo\bar.txt"

Comment: These methods are depricated in .NET and the standard Environment.NewLine should be used. And since the OP was looking at ASP.NET, these constants wouldn't work anyway. HTML <BR/> tags are the correct way to provide the solution sought.

Comment: I was referring to the VB6 style constants. Just so we are clear. I still wouldn't have voted this down though.

Comment: @John, actually you are wrong.  The vb constants are in no way deprecated.

Comment: These constants are carryovers from the classic VB (and exists in the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly). They are meant for easy migration to .Net. 

Using them in non-VB projects will create an assembly dependency on Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

With .Net Core, there's more reasons to prefer Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using something like this.

```
Response.Write("Hello \r\n")
Response.Write("World \r\n")
```

and the output is

```
Hello\r\nWorld\r\n
```

Then you are basically looking for something like this

```
Response.Write("Hello <br/>")
Response.Write("World <br/>")
```

This will output

```
Hello 
World
```

you can also just define "<br />" as constant and reuse it

eg.

```
Public Const HtmlNewLine as string ="<br />"
Response.Write("Hello " &  HtmlNewLine) 
Response.Write("World " &  HtmlNewLine)
```

Comment: If you want to go all out, you could even subclass Environment and add the HtmlNewLine to it...

Comment: :) yes John. Also we can add as Extension methods if need be.

Answer (score 7):

it's :

`vbnewline`

for example

`Msgbox ("Fst line" & vbnewline & "second line")`

Comment: This worked in a Reporting Services textbox expression perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Comment: this won't do anything for a web environment.  You need a <br /> tag

Answer (score 3):

Your need to use the [html/xhtml break character](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp):

```
<br />
```

Answer (score 3):

you can solve that problem in visual basic .net without concatenating your text, you can use this as a return type of your overloaded Tostring:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(String.format("FirstName:{0} \r\n LastName: {1}", "Nordanne", "Isahac"))
```

Answer (score 3):

In  asp.net  for giving  new line character in string you should use `<br>` .

For window base application `Environment.NewLine` will work fine.

Comment: this is  right answer now  i am able to write string  messege in new  line with  the help of <br> tag.

Answer (score 2):

```
VbCr
```

Try that.

Comment: VbCr = "\r".  vbCrLf = "\r\n" and is much more common

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I can use `vbNewLine`, `vbCrLf` or `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

`vbCrLf` is a relic of Visual Basic 6 days. Though it works exactly the same as `Environment.NewLine`, it has only been kept to make the .NET api feel more familiar to VB6 developers switching.

You can call the String.Replace() function to avoid concatenation of many single string values.

MsgBox ("first line \n second line.".Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine))

Comment: Or something like: MessageText = MessageText.Replace("\n", vbNewLine) ?

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` or `vbCrLf` or `Constants.vbCrLf`

More information about VB.NET new line:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the need to store line breaks in a string in a SQL table and have them displayed in vb.NET. My solution was to include a string like this in my database:

```
"This is the first line{0}This is the second{0}This is the third"
```

In vb.NET, I processed the string like this before using it:

```
Label2.Text = String.Format(stringFromSQLquery, vbCrLf)
```

This replaces every occurance of {0} with vbCrLf

Answer (score 0):

To get specifically \r\n in VB.Net, you can use System.Convert.ToChar like this :

```
' New Line = Carriage Return + Line Feed
Dim nl = Convert.ToChar(13) & Convert.ToChar(10)
```

This solution doesn't depend on the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly like `vbCrLf` and provides a fixed value, unlike `Environment.NewLine` which varies according the platform.