# Remove last characters (empty lines) in vb .NET

Tags: vb.net, newline, filestream

I have to remove the last empty lines of a file programmatically in vb .NET. Sometimes, there is only one empty line, sometimes two (but never more).

I use these lines of code for now on :

```
fs = New FileStream(Fic_source, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
fs.Seek(-50, SeekOrigin.End)
Dim strEOF As String = New StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd()
strEOF = strEOF .Replace(vbCrLf, "")  ' 
strEOF = strEOF .Replace("\r", "")    ' Removes every CR / LF / CRLF from the end of the file
strEOF = strEOF .Replace("\n", "")    '
strEOF = String.Concat(strEOF , vbCrLf) ' adds an empty line to finish the file correctly
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to replace the last 50 characters from my stream to strEOF, anyone got an idea ?

Comment: How does "sometimes two (but never more)" translate into "last 50 characters"?  Please be more precise in your question.  Also, read the FAQ and see if you can make your question apply to a broad audience.  As it is your question is much too localized and is bound to get closed without an answer.

Comment: I don't think `strEOF.Replace("\r", "")` will actually replace vbCr with an empty string. Same for `"\n"`. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515722/new-line-character-in-vb-net).

Comment: You should not use C style escaping in VB. Your Replace function is looking *literally* for "\r" and "\n" -- and *not* looking for ASCII 13 ("\r") and ASCII 10 ("\n")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I would be looking at changing the length of the file - try SetLength on the filestream.  Flush and close.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the data in the stream converted to a string, then use regular expressions to match and replace the possibility of the multiple CRLFs. One nuance of the regex processesor is that you can tell it to work right to left; hence starting at the end.

The following pattern will start at the end ($) and replace any CRLF (up to two sets, or four characters either being \r\n) with just one CRLF. If there are none, then it will *replace* (actually put) one in at the very end even if it doesn't match any of the character set.

```
dim data = string.Format("ABC{0}DEF{0}{0}", Environment.NewLine) ' 2 CRLF
dim pattern = "[\r\n]{0,4}$"

Console.WriteLine( "***{0}***", Regex.Replace( data, pattern, Environment.NewLine, RegexOptions.RightToLeft) )

data = string.Format("ABC{0}DEF", Environment.NewLine) ' No CRLFS

Console.WriteLine( "***{0}***", Regex.Replace( data, pattern, Environment.NewLine, RegexOptions.RightToLeft) )

' Console Results (note that *** is following each DEF
'***ABC
'DEF
'***
'***ABC
'DEF
'***
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to trim CR and LF from the end of the text you have, so you might as well use .TrimEnd:

```
strEOF = strEOF.TrimEnd(vbCrLf.ToArray) & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim objWriter As New StreamWriter(FileNamewithPath, True)
objWriter.NewLine = Chr(10) 'This works as ENTER on keyboard. This is optional.
objWriter.WriteLine("The text that is required to write")
'Loop it to get all the values you need to write.
'Before the last line. i.e. before your end loop - 1 step
objWriter.NewLine = "" 'add this
objWriter.WriteLine("last line to be written").
objWriter.Close()
```